# web3js.eth.getAccounts() and ethersjs.listAccounts() always returning one account in an array even when more are in metamask?

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethereumjs

I have tested `web3js.eth.getAccounts()` of [web3js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3) and `ethers.listAccounts()` of [etherjs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/single-page/) and they are returning an array with a single account although my metamask has one or more accounts.

Is this the way they are intended to work? ANd if yes, then why have a method like `listAccounts()`? Instead of `listAccount()` and why return an array instead of a single item?

In what circumstances will the methods mentioned above return an array of more than one account?

Comment: are you using truffleHD provider with metamask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [metamask docs](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#eth-requestaccounts):

```
eth_requestAccounts
```

**Returns**

`string[]` - An array of a single, hexadecimal Ethereum address string.

**Description**

Requests that the user provides an Ethereum address to be identified by. Returns a Promise that resolves to an array of a single Ethereum address string. If the user denies the request, the Promise will reject with a 4001 error.

**from this [github issue](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/5607)**

For privacy reasons, we only expose the account the user has selected. It would be pretty shady if we let any site request every single account address in your MetaMask.

If the user explicitly allows access to multiple accounts then array has more than one items, but this is not updated in docs or any of the issue.

This is default behaviour (allowing only selected account)
[image]

If it is changed to allow access to multiple accounts, then array has more than one item:
[image]